# Responding differently to different url changes with history.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, history.js, html5-history

I'm using history.js, and want to call content via ajax when the url changes. I have that working, but the issue is that I need the page to respond differently depending on what URL is loaded when the state changes. For example, within a local scope, I need the pages related to URLs on the right hand nav to load into the content area next to them. If the URL changes to a scope outside of the section I'm in, I want the ajax call to load pages in a container that contains the whole section, including the right hand nav. How can I respond differently to URLs reliably using history.js?

**Example:**

I have some code that changes the URL when right hand nav items are clicked:

```
var History = window.History;

$('#right-hand-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  var place = $(this).attr('href');

  History.pushState("", "page title", place);  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

...and some code that loads different content when the URL changes:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
  var State      = History.getState()
      subContent = $('#sub-content');

  $.ajax({
    url: State.url,
    beforeSend : function() {
     // Would start pre-loader code
    },
    success    : function(result) {
     // Would end pre-loader code
     subContent.html(result);
    } 

  });
});
```

But, what if I want the `onstatechange` event handler to react differently if the new url is outside of this sub-section? What if I want it to replace `$('#primary-content').html()` instead of `$('#sub-content').html()` if the new URL causes the AJAX request to pull content that doesn't belong in `$('#sub-content')`?:

**Basic HTML:**

```
<section id="primary-content">
  <section id="sub-content">
  </section>
  <nav id="sub-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

**When URL changes to:** www.example.com/sub-section/page.html

```
<section id="primary-content">
  <section id="sub-content">
    <!-- ajax should load content here -->
  </section>
  <nav id="sub-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

**When URL changes to:** www.example.com/page.html

```
<section id="primary-content">
    <!-- ajax should load content here -->
</section>
```

How do you safely determine when the URL goes to a different section using `history.js`? How do you react to that change?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a router abstraction on top of History.js, which is a rather low-level API, to route URLs to different functions of yours. I have for instance written a History.js routing library called [StateRouter.js](https://github.com/aknuds1/staterouter.js). It's in very early stages of development, but if you find it missing the functionality to solve your problem, I'd love to hear from you. To see what the API has to offer, please look at the Jasmine tests in 'spec/StateRouterSpec.js'. You can apply StateRouter.js like so:

```
var router = new staterouter.Router();
router
  .route('/', loadHomePage)
  .route('/page.html', loadSection)
  .route('/sub-section/page.html', loadSubsection);
// Perform routing of the current state
router.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to distinguish different urls and determine the 'container' element.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function()
{
    var State = History.getState(),
        containerElement;

    // Use regex to distinguish urls
    if (/\/sub-url$/i.test(State.url))
    {
        containerElement = $("#sub-content");
    }
    else
    {
        containerElement = $("#primary-content");
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: State.url,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            // Would start pre-loader code
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
            // Would end pre-loader code
            containerElement.html(result);
        }
    });
});
```